# Error message in if (!class(sub_strat_sett_mat) == "matrix") { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: python, r

Please, i am runing a gridsample alogrithm using R studio 4.3 and i encounter this warning message

`"Error in if (!class(sub_strat_sett_mat) == "matrix") { : the condition has length > 1"`

what am i getting wrong. please help

*specify number of cores to use during parallel processing and type of parallel processing*
`total_ncores <- detectCores()  # this gives the number of cores for your computing system ncores <- total_ncores - 1     # want to use all but 1 core for the parallel processing if(ncores == 0) ncores <- 1 par_type <- "PSOCK"`            # parallel processing type - "PSOCK" for windows, "FORK" for linux, unix, mac

i try to find the total number of the cores on my system and change it to the specifiction but result still comes with error

Comment: Why the python tag?

Comment: This is a bug in the function you are using. The issue is that `sub_strat_sett_mat` has more than one classes in its class attribute, which is valid for objects. The person who wrote the function needs to study `help("inherits")`.

Comment: thanks @Roland,  I will study it further, But is there anything you can do to help me understand it much better on the error? I am trying to grid sample algorithm in R to generate PSUs. Do you have any idea on this

Comment: I have diagnosed the bug in my previous comment (as much as possible with the available information).